# Efficient computation of the extension of a linear basis to completion when the basis is almost complete (ideally using LAPACK routines)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lapack, numerical-analysis

I have a $p \times n$ matrix $B$ (where $n < p$) with orthonormal columns and would like to find a numerically efficient way to extend this matrix to get a complete $p$-dimensional orthonormal basis. In other words I want to compute a $p$ by $p-n$ complementary matrix $W$ so that

$[B|W]$

is orthonormal.

At the moment I am computing the QR factorisation of the rank $p-n$ projection matrix

$P=I-BB^T= QR$

using the LAPACK routines `dgeqp3` and `dorgqr` and discarding the trailing $p$ columns of $Q$. I feel sure that there must be a more efficient method because in my application $B$ is almost a complete basis i.e $p-n$ is small.

I have wondered about building a complementary basis $R$ recursively by working through the columns of $P$. At each step adding a column $C$ to the current $R$ only if $\det([R|C]^T[R|C)\neq0$. After I have $p-n$ independent vectors in $R$ I could form $W$ as $W=(R^TR)^{-1/2} R$. However, I'm not sure if this is a numerically stable solution, or if there is another more efficient method.

Ideally I would like a method I can implement using standard LAPACK routines.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for the [Scientific Computing site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you might want to delete this and repost it on [Computational Science stack exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, also asked [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/efficient-computation-of-the-extension-of-a-linear-basis-to-completion-when-the).